# Getting first element in each group in couchDB

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb

I have a problem like this. Let's say I have a document in CouchDB:

```
{
  _id : "some_uuid",
  _rev : "some_rev",

  country : "Greece",
  city : "Athens",
  name : "John Smith",
  entrance_date : "18 III 2015",
  some_other_data_in_big_json : {}
}
```

Now. I would like to have a view, where I could read only the last document (sorted by entrance_date), but for each country and city. So I would like to see who is the last person who entered Athens in Greece. The last person who entered Berlin in Germany... etc.

In SQL I would do something like joins grouping and multiple selects... but here I am stuck. How to do this the most efficient way?

Answer (score 1):

Create a view with the multipart key:

```
emit([doc.country,doc.city,doc.entrance_date], doc.name)
```

Your `doc.entrance_date` value should be formatted to the pattern `YYYY-MM-DD` to enable automatically sorting in chronological order.

**Request-Use-Case: get the latest user of one city**

```
GET /dbname/_design/ddocname/_view/viewname?startkey=[":country",":city","\u0000"]&startkey=[":country",":city","\u9999"]&descending=true&limit=1
```

How it works:

The whole range of docs for one city is requested. The placeholder `"\u0000"` (the 1st Unicode character) and `"\u9999"` (the last Unicode character) ensuring that such an request not have to specify exact timestamps. Because all rows for one city will be sorted in chronological order from past to present automatically the request should ask for reversed sorting via `descending=true`. Finally `limit=1` returns only the newest row.

**Request-Use-Case: get the latest users of all cities**

In the use-case before one request per city have to be done. If all users of all cities should be responded by CouchDB in one response the view have to be reduced.

Please request a more detailed explanation for this use-case in a comment when you need it.

Comment: Not the original user but interested in a similar request for part 2. I have a similar data structure, device id and then time of interaction. I need to get the time each device was interacted with last in 1 request.

Comment: The time my answer was written I would have explained to introduce a reduce step to get that information. But meanwhile the CouchDB got the `POST /{db}/_find` endpoint which offers a query language to get such results very flexible and easy.

Please have look into https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/find.html

Answer (score 0):

This could be easily done by using the emit() function multiple times. For Example:

```
emit([doc.entrance_date, doc.country], doc.name);
emit([doc.entrance_date, doc.city], doc.name);
```

The resulting view will automatically order the results by data, if that is in a format that will order as you need, like "2015-05-04".
See the documentation for the needed bits like, creating a view and fetching data from it.

Comment: I am not sure if I have been understood correctly. If I do something like you said I will end up with 2 documents per one query: one with key doc.country second one with key doc.city... I would like to get something like this:

**Greece**:
-_Athens_: Last entered: John Smith
-_Thessalloniki_: Last entered: Bill Bucket,
-_Sparta_: Last Entered: Adam Willow,
**Germany**:
 -_Berlin_: Last entered: Hanz Gutt.
 -_Munchen_: Last entered: Gregor Schweinschteiger,
 -_Dortmund_: Last entered: Bastian Klose

How to achieve something like this with multiple emits?